# There are any kind o "sendKeys" command on windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, keyboard, sendkeys

I would like to make a task in my phone that should send keys to it.. 
In fact i will simulate a remote keyboard to my device. So, there is any way to acess send keys on the device?
Thanks

Edit.

ultrashot from XDA Developers told me to use this:

```
keybd_event(<key code>, 0, KEYEVENTF_SILENT, 0);
keybd_event(<key code>, 0, KEYEVENTF_SILENT | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

But i have no idea how to use this.. Its possible to use this with DLLImport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just send a Byte Stream of your Keys pressed, you can get the Byte from each Key of your keyboard using the Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes(string) and then decode using Encoding.Ascii.GetString(bytes)

with Mango supporting Sockets you can use a Simple Socket Client, use the Sockets Receive and Send Methods to retrieve the Byte stream which you can then use to populate a text box or something

its not as easy as SendKeys but this is an alternative

Comment: yeo, but i would to send my computer keyboard to the wp.

Comment: you can do that, aslong as the windows phone establishes a connection to your computer you can send the information from your computer to the windows phone using sockets. Have a look at this tutorial on a basic chat client, you can easily modify the code to have your pc write into textboxes on your phone. http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3918/socket-programming-in-c-part-1/

Comment: What im trying to do is control all applications. Like a Bluetooth keyboard. Unfortunately the keyboard profile is not supported on WP.. So that is what I want. Unfortunately seems that is no way to send a key event that can be captured by any application as I dreamed  . Thanks for everyone

Comment: ultrashot from XDA Developers told me to use this: 


`keybd_event(<key code>, 0, KEYEVENTF_SILENT, 0); 
keybd_event(<key code>, 0, KEYEVENTF_SILENT | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); `



 But i have no idea how to use this.. Its possible to use this with DLLImport?

Comment: @Daniel Santos: No.  You cannot use DllImport in a Windows Phone application at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems with your scenarion:

1. There is no way to programaticaly simulate user interaction. There may be some low-level API, but this API is locked away for all developers except MS and partners.
2. There is no way to run your code, while some other application is running. So you can only control your own applications. And if you control your own application, then adding explicit logic to remotely add text into textbox shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 1):

Other than directly sending input to a control - **no**. You don't have access to an API like `SendKeys` from the stock SDK.

Answer (score 1):

"sendkeys" works on the Desktop by sending windows messages to controls; that level of operation isn't available at the managed level on Windows Phone.  You'd have to go lower level either as a phone vendor by contacting Microsoft to get and SDK at the native level.  But, I doubt you'd be able to do something like that at any level.